# java comparing integers as strings with a comparator - odd results

Tags: java, int, comparator, dereference

I'm attemping to compare some players with a comparator by the amount of runs they have obtained.

```
System.out.println("Comparing: " + p2.getRuns() + " and " + p1.getRuns());
int newRESULT = intConvert(p2.getRuns()).compareTo(intConvert(p1.getRuns()));
System.out.println("Returns: " + newRESULT);
return newRESULT;
```

However this returns:

Comparing: 25 and 0,
Returns: 2

Comparing: 0 and 100,
Returns: -1

Comparing: 25 and 100,
Returns: 1

...and hence orders the players in the wrong order.

Should the first comparison not return 1, the second -1 and the last -1 as well?

intConvert:

```
     private static String intConvert(int x)
     {
      return "" + x;
     }
```

Comment: Note that `compareTo` doesn't have to return -1 or 1, it could return smaller or bigger values as well. Basically the convention is: < 0 means smaller, == 0 means equal and > 0 means greater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `intConvert(...)` converts an `int` to a `String`, and thus you get lexical comparisons which meahs `"25"` is greater than `"100"` because the first character is greater (2 > 1).

If you want to get correct comparisons stick to comparing `int`s or if you need to use a `String` create strings of equal length and fill in missings zeros at the front (e.g. `25 -> "025")`.

Answer (score 0):

To compare `Numbers` that are represented as `String` in a sensible way, you need to consistently format them all the same way.

[`String`s use lexical comparisons.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064633/string-comparison-in-java) This means `"5"` will be `>` `"20"` because `5` is `>` than `2`. To get the logically expected output you need to format the numbers with some kind of formatter to make them lexically comparable.

`"05"` is `<` `"20"`

The simplest thing would be to use [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and a pattern to format all the numbers to `Strings` so they will compare consistently lexically.

```
String.format("%04d", yourInteger);
```

This will produce all `int`s that are passed in as left padded with `0` for 4 positions.

```
String.format("%04d", 5);
```

will produce `0005`

Make the `"%0Xd"` where `X` is the number of digits you want it formatted to.

Comment: Can `X` be a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert the numbers to strings just to sort, you can do something like:

```
class ComparePlayersByRuns implements Comparator<Player> {
    public int compareTo(Player p1, Player p2) {
        return p1.getRuns().compareTo(p2.getRuns());
    }
}
```

or in Java 8 and later all you need to create your comparator is:

```
Comparators.comparing(Player::getRuns);
```

And no, the compare isn't required to return 1, 0, or -1, the documentation says:

> Returns:
>
> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.