# How I can get the maximum version?

Tags: java

How can I sort the following array, `String`?

```
String[] s = {"0.1", "0.3", "0.6", "0.4", "0.5", "0.2", "0.7", "0.8", "0.9", "0.10"};
```

By sort I don't mean here converting it into in an integer and get the result as `0.9`.

Here I want to get the value as `0.10`.

Here in this case if the string array contains `1.1` then the maximum value will be `1.1`.

I am able to get the maximum value if the array is like this, i.e.,

```
String[] s = {"0.1", "0.4", "0.3", "0.4", "0.5", "0.2", "0.7", "1.8", "2.9", "3.1"};
```

My code will work for this string array, but suppose if the

```
String[] s = {"0.1", "1.4", "1.3", "0.4", "0.5", "0.2", "2.7", "1.8", "2.9", "0.1"};
```

My code.

```
public String createNewVersion(
            String[] entityVersionHistory) {

Map<Integer, List<Integer>> m_Map1 = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();

String prevKey = "0";
String currentKey = null;

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (String str: entityVersionHistory)
{
    String[] splitVersion = str.split("\\.");
    currentKey = splitVersion[0];
    if(!prevKey.equals(currentKey))
    {
        Integer s = new Integer(splitVersion[1]);

        m_Map1.put(Integer.valueOf(prevKey), list);
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(s);

        prevKey = currentKey;
    }
    else
    {
        Integer s = new Integer(splitVersion[1]);
        list.add(s);
    }
}
m_Map1.put(Integer.valueOf(prevKey), list);
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Why downvote ? If somebody has read the question well , he can only get the difficulty of this problem when he will try this

Comment: By what criteria are you determining "max"? The only way "0.9" > "0.10" is by length of the string (or, I suppose, by position in your specific array).

Comment: @vikiii: Why isn't the maximum `0.9`?

Comment: Maybe you want to do a lexicographical comparison?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064633/string-comparison-in-java

Comment: @iamnotmaynard it's about version numbers, so 0.10 > 0.9

Comment: @AlexisPigeon Ah, I see.

Comment: @Blender it's about version numbers, so 0.10 > 0.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically [Anny-Mousse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14143747/1749753) in code: The restriction is, there are only digits and dots allowed in a version number.

```
public class Version implements Comparable<Version> {

    private int[] version;

    public Version(String str) {
        if (!str.matches("\\d+[.\\d]*?\\d")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Version must start and end with digit and"
                    + "only contain digits and dots."
                    + " You provided '" + str + "'");
        }
        String[] tokens = str.split("\\.");
        version = new int[tokens.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            version[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i], 10);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Version other) {
        Version shorterOne =
                this.version.length < other.version.length ?
                this : other;
        int min = shorterOne.version.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
            if (this.version[i] != other.version[i]) {
                return this.version[i] - other.version[i];
            }
        }
        return this.version.length - other.version.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(2 * version.length);
        for (Integer i : version) {
            str.append(i).append('.');
        }
        return str.deleteCharAt(str.length() - 1).toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] s = {"1.4","1.3","0.4","0.5","0.2","2.7","1.8","2.9","0.1"};
        List<Version> list = new ArrayList<>(s.length);
        for (String str : s) {
            list.add(new Version(str));
        }
        Version max = Collections.max(list);
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Comment: damn, you were quicker, +1 for speed

Comment: @jlordo I am getting error in this line List<Version> list = new ArrayList<>(s.length); . Is this correct?

Comment: Are you using Java 7? If not, you need `List<Version> list = new ArrayList<Version>(s.length);` It would be better if you would specify your error. Maybe you are missing `import java.util.List;` and `import java.util.ArrayList;`

Comment: Thanks jlordo. Exactly what i needed. But can't it be solved using simpler taking array or a map.

Comment: IMHO, `Collections.max` on a `Comparable` type is pretty simple. And having a `Version` class follows the OOP principle, so I think my answer is pretty simple.

Answer (score 5):

It's not as easy as you think in general. Because there are version numbers such as `3.1beta`, too. I'm not going to discuss these fully below, just sketch a number of challenges that arise.

But the basic idea is as follows:

1. **split** the string at `.` into an array, converting the individual components into integers.
2. **compare component-wise**. If two numbers agree on the first component, skip to the next.

So, given the version numbers `3.10.1` and `3.9.2` we convert them first to an array of integers: `{ 3, 10, 1 }` and `{3, 9, 2}`. Then we test the first component, but `3 == 3`, so we skip to the next component. `10 > 9`, so the result is that the first is larger.

Now if you want to support `beta` and similar things, it gets really messy. Take Debian version numbering for examples. In addition to dots, it has an *epoch* separator. So a verision of `2:1.0 > 2.0` (a new epoch is larger than the previous epochs numbering). A `-` separates a revision number. So `2-2 < 2.1-1`, because `2 < 2.1` (and the revision is secondary to the main version number!). There are also *negative* versions. So `1.0~beta < 1.0`, but `1.0final > 1.0` - read this as "1.0 minus beta" and "1.0 plus final".

There is no unique standard for how these are to be read. There is just the common convention that `.` separate lower-priority components, while `~` is a popular indicator for pre-releases (which is why it should sort before the non-postfixed version).

Answer (score 1):

Try as

```
    Arrays.sort(s, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            String[] a1 = o1.split("\\.");
            String[] a2 = o2.split("\\.");
            int c1 = Integer.parseInt(a1[0]) - Integer.parseInt(a2[0]);
            if (c1 != 0) {
                return c1;
            }
            return a1[1].compareTo(a2[1]);
        }

    });
```