# freemarker - string comparison - operator not allowed

Tags: java, freemarker, string-comparison

I want to compare two strings to decide whether the first string is 'smaller' than the second string.

```
<#if name1 <= name2>
....
</#if>
```

Error:

```
Can't use operator "<=" on string values.
```

Can this be done in FreeMarker? Is it possible to call the `String.compareTo` method in a template?

Comment: If they're String objects, you should use `String.compareTo()`. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) could help.

Comment: Both are indeed String objects. How can I call the `compareTo` method in FreeMarker?

Comment: also depends on what you consider to be "smaller". Strings are not numerical values.

Comment: @Stultuske The definition of `String.compareTo()` is OK for my case.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to compare strings in a template like that?

Answer (score 2):

If you meant length, you can use the `length` built-in, for example:

```
<#if string?length gt 0>
```

If you mean to use a custom comparison and you are using Struts2, you can simply invoke an action method for it, let's assume you have a compare method:

```
public boolean compare(String str1, String str2) { ... }
```

then you can do this:

```
<#if action.compare(str1, str2) gt 0>
```

Comment: How does the FreeMarker engine find the `compare` function? Where should it be implemented? Does it have to be `static`?

Comment: Well, here I assumed, that you are using Struts2. If this is not the case, it won't. If you do, it must be a public instance method of a Struts2 Action.

Comment: No I am not using Struts2.

Comment: If you add any plain Java object with public methods to your data-model, or to the set of configuration-level shared variables, you can call its methods. You can also implement `TemplateMethodModelEx` and add that to your data-model or to your shared variables or pull it in in an `#import`-ed template like `<#assign strCmp = 'com.example.MyStringComparatorTemplateModel'?new()>`.

Answer (score 0):

In FreeMarker you can use `==` to compare `Strings`, but depending the meaning of `<=` for you, you can use [BuiltIn for strings](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html) to compare the `lenght`, the `content`, or what you need.

**UPDATE**: you don't have built in method to [compare lexicographically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064633/string-comparison-in-java) `String` in `FreeMarker`, so you have 2 options:

1. Create your own method to compare the `Strings` with `built-in` functions,  iterating over strings and comparing char by char.
2. create a `Java` comparator as [@meskobalazs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102532/meskobalazs) suggest

Comment: what you mean with `<=` ?

Comment: The definition of `String.compareTo()` is OK for my case.