# Comparing Strings lexicographically new approach fails for one test case

Tags: java, string, string-comparison, compareto, lexicographic

I was asked to check whether `String a` is lexicographically larger `String b`. So even before thinking about `compareTo()` method I got a new idea.

1. Take the minimum of the lengths of both a & b.
2. Iterate a for loop till that minimum length and store the sum of `ascii`'s of each characters in both a & b separately.
3. Compare the `ascii`'s to print the result.

Here is my code

```
private static void isInLexicographicOrder(String a, String b) {
    char[] arr1 = a.toCharArray();
    int asciCount1 = 0;

    char[] arr2 = b.toCharArray();
    int asciCount2 = 0;

    long asciLength = (a.length() < b.length()) ? a.length() : b.length();
    for(int i=0; i<asciLength; i++) {
        asciCount1 += arr1[i];
        asciCount2 += arr2[i];
    }

    if(asciCount1 < asciCount2) {
        System.out.println("In Lexicographic Order");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not In Lexicographic Order");
    }

}
```

It is working fine for many inputs I provided, then I found this link [String Comparison in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064633/string-comparison-in-java), so for confirmation I used compare to method in my code.

```
System.out.println((a.compareTo(b)) < 0 ? "In Lexicographic Order" : "Not In Lexicographic Order");
```

Now when I submitted the code the other website is saying that the code is failing for one test case

Sample input

```
vuut
vuuuuu
```

They are want output to come as `No` ie, `Not In Lexicographic Order`. But my logic and the `compareTo()` logic says `In Lexicographic Order`. So whats wrong, Is my logic is completely correct?

This is the link where I got the [Question.](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-strings-introduction?utm_campaign=challenge-recommendation&utm_medium=email&utm_source=37-day-campaign) Sorry if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is not correct. Comparing the sums of the characters is wrong, since "bab", "abb" and "bba" will have the same value, but that tells you nothing regarding which of them comes first lexicographicaly.

You should compare each pair of characters separately. The first time you encounter a pair of characters not equal to each other, the one with the lower value belongs to the String that should come first.

```
for(int i=0; i<asciLength; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] > arr2[i]) {
        System.out.println("Not In Lexicographic Order");
        return;
    } else if (arr1[i] < arr2[i]) {
        System.out.println("In Lexicographic Order");
        return;
    }
}
// at this point we know that the Strings are either equal or one 
// is fully contained in the other. The shorter String must come first
if (arr1.length <= arr2.length) {
    System.out.println("In Lexicographic Order");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not In Lexicographic Order");
}
```

Comment: that's right I had this feeling that somewhere I'm wrong

Comment: but the sample input I provided, it is in lexicographic order right?

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran Yes, it is.

Answer (score 2):

The `comareTo` method iterates over the characters of the two strings until it reaches a position where the two characters differ. The return-value is the difference between the two codepoint values.

Your implemenation adds all the codepoints to a sum and returns the difference of the result of this addition.

Try your method with the values `abcd` and `dcba`. I expect your method to return `0`instead of a negative number

Comment: Nice comparison (pun intended). However, your terminology is wrong. It is UTF-16 code units that are being compared. Consider, `"".compareTo("＊")) == "".compareTo("＊"))` because  and have two code units each, with the first one the same, while ＊ has one. So, they differ from ＊ as the same point therefore `compareTo` returns the same number.