# Sort alphanumeric values in java as it is done in db2

Tags: java, sorting, db2, dataset

Executing a query in db2 database, sorts the alphanumeric values of a column as numbers first and alphabets later. However if we try to implement the same in java code it sorts as numbers first and alphabets later (i.e. lexiographic sorting based on ascii code)

```
 Eg. Original Dataset {AA100, 34, 56, BB200,}
 DB2 Sorted Dataset {AA100, BB200, 34, 56}
 Java Sorted Dataset {34, 56, AA100, BB200}
```

How can i change this to show alphabet values first and numeric values last?

Comment: Take a look [lexiographic sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064633/string-comparison-in-java)

Comment: How to compare is java 101. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718383/why-should-a-java-class-implement-comparable

Comment: @user6804978 did you solved the problem? I have the same issue...